# How to remove the Cookies popup in Selenium Python for multiple websites?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, cookies

I have a Selenium Script as follows, which goes through each website and take its screenshot, and save it locally.

```
try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, options=chrome_options)
    driver.get(link)

    
    # Define zoom levels and frame count (adjust as needed)
    frame_count = 30  # Number of frames for each zoom level
    zoom_step = 0.02  # Zoom step size
    
    frames = []

    for zoom_level in range(frame_count + 1):
        current_zoom = 1.0 + (zoom_level - frame_count / 2) * zoom_step
        current_zoom = max(current_zoom, 0.1)  # Limit minimum zoom to 10%
        
        
        zoom_css = f"scale({current_zoom})"
        driver.execute_script(f'document.body.style.transform = "{zoom_css}";')
        
        
        screenshot = driver.get_screenshot_as_png()
        img = Image.open(BytesIO(screenshot))
        frames.append(img)
        
    driver.quit()
    frames[0].save(output_path, save_all=True, append_images=frames[1:], loop=0, duration=30)  # Adjust duration for smoother effect

    return True
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error creating zooming GIF: {str(e)}")
    return False
```

I want to work this code dynamically for multiple websites. But the problem is when Cookies Pop up, it messes the screenshot. How do I handle that dynamically? So that the cookie popup is removed (or accepted) dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to handle this.

One, you could try dismissing any alert that may be present before you take your screenshot:

```py
try:
    driver.switch_to.alert.dismiss()
except Exception:
    pass
```

Or Two, you could try setting Chrome options to prevent some alerts from appearing in the first place:

```py
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {}
prefs["default_content_settings.popups"] = 0
prefs["managed_default_content_settings.popups"] = 0
prefs["profile.default_content_settings.popups"] = 0
prefs["profile.managed_default_content_settings.popups"] = 0
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: I have tried both of these methods, but none is working :(